# Does Google analitycs allow to add custom track id to event?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In my Javascript code i have got function to track custom event:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Open track', 'test');
```

Now, is there a way, to add another track id, so when this custom event track fires, i can send this data to for example:

UA-434341791-2 ?

Thank You for advice.

Comment: You can initialise two instances of the GA client library with two different ID, then use them track different page views. You cannot switch the GA identifier once the JS is initialised on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the event value for this? (its an integer)

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',          // Required.
  'eventCategory': 'Open track',   // Required.
  'eventAction': 'click',      // Required.
  'eventLabel': 'test',
  'eventValue': 4343417912
});
```

Comment: Value  Number  No  Values must be non-negative. Useful to pass counts (e.g. 4 times) - it looks like it's for counts.

Comment: it says "useful" - its up to you how you decide to use it. And if your data is numerical ("UA" does not change) you can use it for that

Comment: And what, when UA is dynamic ?

Comment: well, your question shows 4 string-values passed, and the documentation allows for 5 strings, and one integer passed. Does this not cover your needs?